# dont want to edit particular field which is used in store and update functions

Tags: php, laravel

ProductController

```
public function store()
{
    $product = Product::create($this->validateRequest());

    return redirect('/product');
}

public function update(Product $product)
{
    $product->update($this->validateRequest());

    return redirect('/product');
}

private function validateRequest()
{
    return request()->validate([

        'sub_category_id' => ['required'],

        'name' => ['required', 'min:4'],

        'code' => ['required', 'alpha_dash','unique:products'],

        'description' => ['required', 'min:4'],

        'color' => ['required', 'min:3'],

        'price' => ['required', 'integer'],
    ]);

}
```

here code has unique value from table products. but whenever I edit the form it says code has already taken. so how to execute this without edit the 'code'(its unique).

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore certain ids during the unique check:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

public function store()
{
    Product::create($this->validateRequest(new Product()));

    return redirect('/product');
}

public function update(Product $product)
{
    $product->update($this->validateRequest($product));

    return redirect('/product');
}

private function validateRequest(Product $product)
{
    return request()->validate([
        'sub_category_id' => ['required'],
        'name' => ['required', 'min:4'],
        'code' => ['required', 'alpha_dash', Rule::unique('products')->ignore($product)],
        'description' => ['required', 'min:4'],
        'color' => ['required', 'min:3'],
        'price' => ['required', 'integer'],
    ]);
}
```

Here you either pass the existing model when updating or a new model instance when storing, so the call to `$product->id` either returns `null` when storing a new product so no product in the database is ignored, or the id when updating and then only that product is ignored.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-unique):

> Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID:
>
> Sometimes, you may wish to ignore a given ID during the unique check.
> For example, consider an "update profile" screen that includes the
> user's name, e-mail address, and location. You will probably want to
> verify that the e-mail address is unique. However, if the user only
> changes the name field and not the e-mail field, you do not want a
> validation error to be thrown because the user is already the owner of
> the e-mail address.
>
> To instruct the validator to ignore the user's ID, we'll use the `Rule`
> class to fluently define the rule. In this example, we'll also specify
> the validation rules as an array instead of using the | character to
> delimit the rules:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
    ],
]);
```

Be aware of the following though:

> You should never pass any user controlled request input into the
> ignore method. Instead, you should only pass a system generated unique
> ID such as an auto-incrementing ID or UUID from an Eloquent model
> instance. Otherwise, your application will be vulnerable to an SQL
> injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here is you are using the same rule for creating the product and updating the product.

If you are using the latest Laravel, you may want to read the documentation about form request https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#form-request-validation and create different form request for store and update.

If you still want to use your way, you can try as below

```php
private function validateRequest()
{
    $rules = [
        'sub_category_id' => ['required'],
        'name' => ['required', 'min:4'],
        'description' => ['required', 'min:4'],
        'color' => ['required', 'min:3'],
        'price' => ['required', 'integer'],
    ];
    
    if (request()->isMethod('store')) {
        $rules['code'] = ['required', 'alpha_dash'];
    }

    return request()->validate($rules);
}
```

Please tell me whether it works!

Comment: Your code needs optimisation since it contains redundant code lines.

Comment: Opps, I was want to make it as simple as it is for him to easily understand it. But yeah I updated it. @OMiShah

Comment: You cannot simply remove the unique check when updating, otherwise you can duplicate  the same code when updating products, making the unique check pointless in the store method.

Comment: Rezuan Kassim . its working in first condition using post and the second with patch ..thank you.

Comment: @Remul as my understanding from the questions and from the code, the `code` of `product` should not be editable by user when updating. If the `code` is not supposed to change, it is better to just remove `code` from the rules so that `code` will not be updated.

Comment: @Delvin if `code` is not supposed to be update when updating, it is better just remove it from the rule when updating `product`, because in the example I have given the `code` will still be updated. And if I helped you, please make set this as answer by clicking the `mark`

Comment: @RezuanKassim I agree with you, if the code should not be updated, then the rules array should not contain a `code` entry, but in your solution you are only appending the unique rule when the method is store, the code entry is still present (required, alpha_dash), so it will still be updated when a code is provided, it just won't check uniqueness when updating, which means you can duplicate codes while updating.

Comment: @Remul I understood what you mean and I have updated the solution. Thanks 

Answer (score 0):

Try this, proper and clean code

**ProductController**

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule; // add this

public function store()
{
    $product = Product::create($this->validateRequest());

    return redirect('/product'); //use route instead of URL
}

public function update(Product $product)
{
    $product->update($this->validateRequest($product->id));

    return redirect('/product'); //use route instead of URL
}

private function validateRequest($id = null)
{
    return request()->validate([
        'sub_category_id' => 'required',
        'name' => 'required|min:4',
        'code' => 'required|alpha_dash|' . Rule::unique('products')->ignore($id),
        'description' => 'required|min:4',
        'color' => 'required|min:3',
        'price' => 'required|integer',
    ]);
}
```

Suggest to use [Form request validation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#form-request-validation)